# Change the weight of an Edge of a path in a open street map based igraph based on a list of gps coordinates

Tags: r, navigation, igraph, osrm, osmar

i would like to change weight of parts of a route based on gps coordinates.
For that i would like to get gps coordinates of an edge of a calculated route then compare them with a list of coordinates i have and if the coordinates in my list matches the coordinates of an endge of a route, i would like to change the weight of that edge.
Currently i have the code that calculates the route and changes the weight of the whole route.
I get the coordinates of the route but i just cant get the steps requiered to get back to the graph.. my brain just shuts down :)

```
library(osmar)
library(igraph)

### Get data ----
src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 1000, 1000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)

### Reduce to highways: ----
hways <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
hways <- find(hways, way(tags(k == "name")))
hways <- find_down(muc, way(hways))
hways <- subset(muc, ids = hways)

#### Plot data ----
## Plot complete data and highways on top:
plot(muc)
plot_ways(muc, col = "lightgrey")
plot_ways(hways, col = "coral", add = TRUE)

### Define route start and end nodes: ----
id<-find(muc, node(tags(v %agrep% "Sendlinger Tor")))[1]
hway_start_node <-find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway"))) 
hway_start <- subset(muc, node(hway_start_node))

id <- find(muc, node(attrs(lon > 11.58 & lat > 48.15)))[1]
hway_end_node <- find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway")))
hway_end <- subset(muc, node(hway_end_node))

## Add the route start and and nodes to the plot:
plot_nodes(hway_start, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2)
plot_nodes(hway_end, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2)

### Create street graph ----
gr <- as.undirected(as_igraph(hways))

### Compute shortest route: ----
# Calculate route
route <- function(start_node,end_node) {
  get.shortest.paths(gr,
                     from = as.character(start_node),
                     to = as.character(end_node), 
                     mode = "all")[[1]][[1]]}
# Plot route
plot.route <- function(r,color) {
  r.nodes.names <- as.numeric(V(gr)[r]$name)
  r.ways <- subset(hways, ids = osmar::find_up(hways, node(r.nodes.names)))
  plot_ways(r.ways, add = TRUE, col = color, lwd = 2)
}


r <- route(hway_start_node,hway_end_node)
color <- colorRampPalette(c("springgreen","royalblue"))(nways)[numway]
plot.route(r,color)

route_nodes <- as.numeric(V(gr)[r]$name)
#We construct a newosmarobject containing only elements 
#related to the nodes defining the route:

route_ids <- find_up(hways, node(route_nodes))
route_muc <- subset(hways, ids = route_ids)

#Route details.
#In order to present route details like street names,
#distances, and directions we have to work directly on the internals of the osmar objects.
#We start by extracting the route’s node IDs (which are in the correct order) 
#and the way IDs       (whichwe have to order)
#where the nodes are members:

node_ids <- route_muc$nodes$attrs$id

way_ids <- local({
  w <- match(node_ids, route_muc$ways$refs$ref)
  route_muc$ways$refs$id[w]
})

#Then we extract the names of the ways in the correct order:>
way_names <- local({
  n <- subset(route_muc$ways$tags, k == "name")
  n[match(way_ids, n$id), "v"]
})

#The next step is to extract the nodes’ coordinates,>
node_coords <- route_muc$nodes$attrs[, c("lon", "lat")]

#and to compute the distances (meters) and the bearings (degrees) 
#between successive nodes (using thepackagegeosphere):

node_dirs <- local({
      n <- nrow(node_coords)
      from <- 1:(n - 1)
      to <- 2:n
      cbind(dist = c(0, distHaversine(node_coords[from,], node_coords[to,])),
            bear = c(0, bearing(node_coords[from,], node_coords[to,])))
    })



#Finally, we pack together all the information, 
#and additionally compute the cumulative distance

route_details <- data.frame(way_names, node_dirs)
route_details$cdist <- cumsum(route_details$dist)
route_details$coord <- node_coords
route_details$id <- node_ids
print(route_details)

#here we select randomly parts from the route

gps_points<-route_details[sample(1:nrow(route_details), 10,replace=FALSE),]
```

here i would like to change the weight of the graph parts based on selected gps coordinates.
i get the way till the point of getting the gps coordinates but i just hang up mentally here to get back to the graph to change the weights there.

```
# Currently i can only Modify current route weight
E(gr)[r]$weight <- E(gr)[r]$weight * 2
```

Thank you for you help!
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script finds the ids of edges adjacent to a list of coordinates (`wished.coord`) so that you can modify the weights :

```
library(osmar)
library(igraph)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

### Get data ----
src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")
muc_bbox <- center_bbox(11.575278, 48.137222, 1000, 1000)
muc <- get_osm(muc_bbox, src)

### Reduce to highways: ----
hways <- subset(muc, way_ids = find(muc, way(tags(k == "highway"))))
hways <- find(hways, way(tags(k == "name")))
hways <- find_down(muc, way(hways))
hways <- subset(muc, ids = hways)

#### Plot data ----
## Plot complete data and highways on top:
plot(muc)
plot_ways(muc, col = "lightgrey")
plot_ways(hways, col = "coral", add = TRUE)

### Define route start and end nodes: ----
id<-find(muc, node(tags(v %agrep% "Sendlinger Tor")))[1]
hway_start_node <-find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway"))) 
hway_start <- subset(muc, node(hway_start_node))

id <- find(muc, node(attrs(lon > 11.58 & lat > 48.15)))[1]
hway_end_node <- find_nearest_node(muc, id, way(tags(k == "highway")))
hway_end <- subset(muc, node(hway_end_node))

## Add the route start and and nodes to the plot:
plot_nodes(hway_start, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2)
plot_nodes(hway_end, add = TRUE, col = "red", pch = 19, cex = 2)

### Create street graph ----
gr <- as.undirected(as_igraph(hways))

### Compute shortest route: ----
# Calculate route
route <- function(start_node,end_node) {
  get.shortest.paths(gr,
                     from = as.character(start_node),
                     to = as.character(end_node), 
                     mode = "all")[[1]][[1]]}
# Plot route
plot.route <- function(r,color) {
  r.nodes.names <- as.numeric(V(gr)[r]$name)
  r.ways <- subset(hways, ids = osmar::find_up(hways, node(r.nodes.names)))
  plot_ways(r.ways, add = TRUE, col = color, lwd = 2)
}
nways <-  1
numway <- 1
r <- route(hway_start_node,hway_end_node)

# Plot route

color <- colorRampPalette(c("springgreen","royalblue"))(nways)[numway]
plot.route(r,color)


## Route details ----
# Construct a new osmar object containing only elements 
# related to the nodes defining the route:
route_nodes <- as.numeric(V(gr)[r]$name)
route_ids <- find_up(hways, node(route_nodes))

osmar.route <- subset(hways, ids = route_ids)
osmar.nodes.ids <- osmar.route$nodes$attrs$id

# Extract the nodes’ coordinates,
osmar.nodes.coords <- osmar.route$nodes$attrs[, c("lon", "lat")]
osmar.nodes <- cbind(data.frame(ids = osmar.nodes.ids),
                     data.frame(ids_igraph = as.numeric(V(gr)[r]) ),
                     osmar.nodes.coords) 


## Find edges ids containing points of interest ----
wished.coords <- data.frame(wlon = c(11.57631),
                            wlat = c(48.14016)) 


# Calculate all distances
distances <- crossing(osmar.nodes,wished.coords) %>%
             mutate(dist = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(lon,lat),cbind(wlon,wlat)))


# Select nodes below maximum distance :
mindist <- 50 #m

wished.nodes <- distances %>% filter(dist < mindist)

# Select edges incident to these nodes :
selected.edges <- unlist(incident_edges(gr,V(gr)[wished.nodes$ids_igraph]))

# Weight of selected edges
E(gr)[selected.edges]$weight
```

Comment: thank you: i get an error Fehler in membership(communities) : Cannot calculate community membership

Comment: on which command of the script do you get this error?

Comment: # Calculate all distances
distances <- crossing(osmar.nodes,wished.coords) %>%
  mutate(dist = geosphere::distHaversine(cbind(lon,lat),cbind(wlon,wlat)))

Comment: did you load packages tidyr, is geosphere installed on your computer?

Comment: Those are packages i load: library(osmar)
library(igraph)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)

Comment: where are values for lon, lat in the line : distHaversine(cbind(lon,lat) are commming from? maybe this is the error?

Comment: from osmar.nodes.coords. I propose to test a complete restart of RStudio to clean-up session

Comment: I sourced script after restart : no error. Result =  E(gr)[selected.edges]$weight
 [1]  9.138732 11.458915 14.286534 11.458915 12.379732 20.426907 17.470794  6.378125 17.470794  6.669311  3.180464
[12] 18.319578  9.897568  3.180464  9.138732  9.897568  6.669311  8.678559 18.443744 14.286534  6.378125

Comment: did a restart, the script works now. Thank you very much again Waldi.

Comment: My pleasure @Andreas!

Comment: this operation selected.edges <- unlist(incident_edges(gr,V(gr)[wished.nodes$ids_igraph])) if i have a lot of gps points is quite slow. Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: to be precise: this operation incident_edges(gr,V(gr)[wished.nodes$ids_igraph]) takes quite a long time. is there a way to optimize it? my wishlist has around 300 rows

Comment: I tried to microbenchmark it on one node : microbenchmark::microbenchmark(incident_edges(gr,V(gr)[wished.nodes$ids_igraph[1]])) and get ~10ms per node, which would suggest 3s for 300 nodes. How long does it take?

Comment: expr      min       lq     mean   median
 selected.edges <- unlist(incident_edges(gr_muc, V(gr_muc)[wished.nodes$ids_igraph[1]])) 50.62764 52.75964 60.83878 53.77717
      uq      max neval
 58.8037 124.7251   100

Comment: nrow(wished.nodes)
[1] 780

Comment: i stopped the time again: it took 46.763 sec  or nrow(wished.nodes)=780 and gsize(gr)=85401 for incident_edges operation. Would be great if it could be optimized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216145/discussion-between-andreas-and-waldi).

Comment: i came back to this solution  because i think the following code :mindist <- 50 #m
wished.nodes <- distances %>% filter(dist < mindist) does contain a logical error. So we have a dataframe of nodes and calculate the distances between the n-node and n+1 node. Then if the distance is smaller than min distance, we filter the node n+1 out and move to next node for compare  after the deleted one and pick next compare. But the problem as i see it we should still check the distance between the first and the 3d node and so on till we find one that satisfies the condition and then move on?

Comment: @Andreas, the code finds all the nodes on the path that are near (less than 50m) points of interest, and modifies the weight of the edges bound to these nodes. Crossing does a cartesian product : we compare all nodes on the path with all nodes available. I don't think there is a n / n+1 logic

Comment: Waldi you a correct i think i mixed up my "problems" sorry for that. Currently im trying to thin out the GPS trace and i used this approach which lead me to beleve it is possible to use this same approach to filter the GPS trace.. which lead to wrong connclusion that there is a n+1 logic. Im realy sorry. This is where im currently stuck .. it looked similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63034689/write-an-efficient-loop-to-compare-gps-coordinates

Comment: OK! did you manage to create the 1km grid with the comment of @Limey, or are you still interested in a solution?

Comment: Im absolutely interrested in a solution!  Currently i just use a "hack"   longitudes <- c(8.9771580802, 13.8350427083)
  latitudes <- c(47.2703623267, 50.5644529365)
  bounding_box <- matrix(c(longitudes, latitudes), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, c("min", "max")))
  projection <- "+proj=longlat"
  sp_box<-Spatial(bbox = bounding_box, proj4string = CRS(projection))
  points_bavaria <- spsample(sp_box, 705000, type="regular")