# Write an efficient loop to compare gps coordinates

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I want to go through a dataframe of GPS coordinates and remove all coordinates that are to close to each other.

```
pick first row
  clalulate the distance between selected and the next row
  if the distance is < mindist and current row is not the last row continue to next row
  else select the current row (leave it in dataframe) and if the selected row is not the last row
   repeat from the begining
```

The result should be a dataframe with gps points that are at least `mindist` away from each other

One aproach was:

```
 node_distances <- function(node_coords)
  {
  n <- nrow(node_coords)
  from <- 1:(n - 1)
  to <- 2:n
  return(c(0, geodist::geodist_vec(node_coords[from, ]$lon,node_coords[from, ]$lat, node_coords[to, ]$lon, node_coords[to, ]$lat, paired = TRUE, measure = "geodesic")))
}
distances %>% filter(dist < mindist)
```

But this aproach only tests 2 rows so that means it creates big gaps in the file.

I started writig nested loops but his is bad decision that does not work and is slow:

```
node_distances_hack <- function(node_coords)
{
  n <- nrow(node_coords)
  for(i in 1:n) {
    print(node_coords[i,])
    a<-i
    distance_c<-0
    mindist<-50
    while(distance_c<mindist || a >= n){
      distance_c<-geodist::geodist_vec(node_coords[i,]$lat,node_coords[i,]$lon,node_coords[a,]$lat,node_coords[a,]$lon, paired = TRUE, measure = "cheap")
      a<-a+1
      }
  }
}
```

What is the better approach?
Thank you in advance,
BR

Comment: This is probably best achieved using `fuzzyjoin::geo_join`. This function can join two dataframes based on the distance between locations. This function works like standard dplyr join operations, except you need to specify the minimum distance between points etc.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for your reply: How would it work on a single dataframe ?

Comment: Maybe: [spatial filtering by proximity in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051141/spatial-filtering-by-proximity-in-r)

Comment: You could use this as a starting point: `tibble::tibble(longitude = c(0, 0,0,10, 10.1), latitude = c(0, 0.1, 10, 10, 10)) %>% 
  fuzzyjoin::geo_left_join(df, max_dist = 10, unit = "km")`. This will join two dataframes, restricting it to coordinates less than 10 km apart

Comment: @Robert i gat an error Fehler in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'tbl_vars' auf Objekt der Klasse "function" angewendet. If i translate it correctly the method in tibble (tbl_vars) can not be used?

Comment: Please check if your packages are up to date

Comment: fuzzyjoin is currently installed and all others seem to be up to date too.

Comment: Does this work? `tibble::tibble(longitude = c(0, 0,0,10, 10.1), latitude = c(0, 0.1, 10, 10, 10))`

Comment: Yes this work no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218359/discussion-between-robert-wilson-and-andreas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without a loop at all by using `geodist:::geodist_xy_vec` to get the distances between each pair of points, since this generates a pairwise matrix. Consider this function:

```r
remove_close <- function(df, CLOSE = 10000)
{
  dist_mat <- geodist:::geodist_xy_vec(df$lon, df$lat, df$lon, df$lat, "cheap")
  diag(dist_mat) <- CLOSE + 1
  clashes <- which(dist_mat < CLOSE, arr.ind = TRUE)
  duplicates <- unique(t(apply(clashes, 1, sort)))[, 2]
  df[-duplicates, ]
}

library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(lat  = runif(1000, 51, 54),
                 lon = runif(1000, 8, 13))

ggplot(df, aes(lon, lat)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(remove_close(df), aes(lon, lat)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Allan, it is working, i need to look at the data a bit further but it seems to work. With CLOSE = 0.001 it is reducing  a dataframe from 1481 rows to 77. What is this rad mesured in?

Comment: @Andreas this is the problem. It is measured in degrees, as latitude and longitude are. This means the absolute distance will change slightly according to latitude. It could be rewritten using the `geodist` function to give an accurate distance if this is required.

Comment: Ok Allan, i need to understand the function OUTER to rewrite this. Thank you very much for your effort so far!

Comment: @Andreas actually, I've realised that `geodist` contains a function that does the same as `outer` for a much easier to interpret and reliable value of `CLOSE` - see my update

Comment: This is awesome, thkank you! But i stick with the previous suggestion since the computation time grew extensively!

Comment: Allan, one maybe stupid question: where did you find the function geodist:::geodist_xy_vec ? :) i cant find a description anywhere.. I just wanted to make sure that it does what i think it does.. ie computing outer product(distance) of two vectors of coordinates. It seems it does it.. i just wanted to see where it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

A method, using the df provided by @Allan Cameron, would use fuzzyjoin. First, you would identify the locations that are close to each other. You would then remove them from the data frame. The example I provide uses a 1 km distance.

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df <- data.frame(latitude  = runif(1000, 51, 54),
             longitude = runif(1000, 8, 13))


close <- df %>% fuzzyjoin::geo_left_join(df, max_dist = 1, unit = "km") %>% 
  filter((longitude.x == longitude.y & latitude.x == latitude.y) == FALSE) %>% 
  rename(longitude = longitude.x, latitude = latitude.x) %>% 
  select(longitude, latitude)


df %>% 
  anti_join(close)
```

Comment: Thank you Robert but i still get this error even if i take your example as it is: Fehler in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'tbl_vars' auf Objekt der Klasse "function" angewendet.

Comment: Strange. This is fine on my machine. This must be an issue with your package installs or some odd system specific issue

Comment: maybe some other package overloads some method?

Comment: try the examples from fuzzyjoin itself https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tigris/versions/0.9.4/topics/geo_join. My initial example explicitly provided the namespace using ::, so I'm sure how it could be overloading

Comment: Thank you Robert i´ll check it out. Ill go with the solution provided by Allan so far. The  spatial filtering by proximity in R suggested by Henrik i tried the function thinning. It was sadly not efficient and took long time to compute und did not produce good result.